# Filter application in adb logcat terminal

Tags: android, adb, logcat

For debugging android applications I want to run logcat in a terminal (`adb logcat`). I've been using short tags for logging (`[Class].class.getSimpleName()`) to distinguish between the entries them more easily. However, `adb logcat` only lets me filter by tag, not by application (like the ADT plugin in Eclipse allows).

The only solution I could come up with is to pipe the logcat through `grep [PID]` but that isn't much help, since the app gets a new PID whenever I run it.

Can anyone offer an idea what might work?

Answer (score 2):

you can try [pidcat](https://github.com/JakeWharton/pidcat) to filter by application , and it's colored output, then just run

```
pidcat yourpackagename
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just create a new filter in logcat, and in application name, put you app name (Package name from manifest), this will create a new filter for you which will only list message thrown by your app in logcat.

Comment: Are you referring to logcat in Eclipse? I have no problem with that. I'm asking about adding application filter when using logcat in terminal.